# Java While(true) thread cleanup

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having trouble cleaning up my threads in a threaded application. I have various runnables that are kicked off using a thread pool. Most of these threads are normal runnables that only execute once on a Scheduled Fixed Rate. Two of them I have are scheduled to run once and have a while(true) loop in them. When I get to cleaning up the threads, it seems I'm having trouble calling ScheduledFuture.close(false) on the threads with the while loop in them. They don't seem to close.

An example of the format of these threads with while loops are:

```
 public void run()
    {


            while (true)
            {
                QueryItem qi = null;
                String query = null;

                try
                {
                    // This is a BlockingQueue!
                    qi = (QueryItem) FB2DatabaseRecorder.dbProcQueue.take();
                    query = qi.getQuery();
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    errorLog.error("Unable to fetch message from message processing queue.");
                }
    // DO SOME STUFF
           }          
}
```

When I try to do the .close() on this thread, it's typically sitting at the blocking queue waiting for an item to come in. Before closing the threads I ensure that the queues are flushed as to not leave any data behind.

Is there a better way to close this type of thread? It seems like it is just not dying with handle.close(false);

Comment: Rather then `while (true)` you should have something like `while (!Thread.interrupted())`

Comment: Thanks. I changed it.

Comment: A google search will point you to the [Java Tutorial on Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html). http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to shutdown your worker thread is to use `Thread.interrupt()`.

Your worker thread is waiting on the `take` call, and the `take` call throws if the thread is interrupted. You can send an `interrupt` and manage the shutdown in the `catch` clause. In code,

```
package stackOv;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

class MyQueueWorker implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Object> q;
    MyQueueWorker(BlockingQueue<Object> q) {
        this.q = q;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Object item = q.take();
                // work here
                System.out.println("obj=" + item);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("worker thread is interrupted");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("interrupted, exiting worker thread");
    }
}

public class InterruptTake {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BlockingQueue<Object> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        Thread worker = new Thread( new MyQueueWorker(q ), "worker" );
        worker.start();
        q.put("hello");
        q.put("world");
        q.put("waiting..");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        worker.interrupt();
    }
}
```